# split row at specific time

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a table from our time series sensor data for the plant. One of the sensor deals with movement of raw product on the belt (voltage / weight scale) before its processed into refinery. Whenever there is a delta (voltage of the belt less or more than normal / weight on belt (*derived to every second*) less or more than target for the 24 hour period (*target ÷ 86,400 seconds ~ rounded to closest ton without decimal* ) we capture it as a new event trigger and row in our warehouse database and move into data lake
We need to find efficiency by work shift (day shift / grave shift) for time periods that cut across shift time

Considering a 2400 tons target on a normal day and day shift between 5:00 AM to 5:00 PM and night shift vice versa, we want the following dataframe:

#### starting dataframe

| row # | event_start | event_end | operation_status | tons_actual | tons_target | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 7:00 AM | 2021-02-01 9:00 AM | normal_run | 197 | 200 |  |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 9:00 AM | 2021-02-01 7:00 PM | curtailed | 700 | 1004 | shift split here |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 7:00 PM | 2021-02-01 11:00 PM | down_for_maintenance | 0 | 301 |  |
| 4 | 2021-02-01 11:00 PM | 2021-02-02 3:00 AM | curtailed | 320 | 402 |  |
| 5 | 2021-02-02 3:00 AM | 2021-02-02 8:00 AM | over_producing | 600 | 502 | shift split here |
| 6 | 2021-02-02 8:00 AM | 2021-02-02 11:00 AM | normal_run | 280 | 301 |  |
| 7 | 2021-02-02 11:00 AM | 2021-02-04 4:00 PM | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 5323 | multiple shift splits here |

to split rows at shift change hours like this:

#### target dataframe

| row # | event_start | event_end | operation_status | tons_actual | tons_target | -------- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 7:00 AM | 2021-02-01 9:00 AM | normal_run | 197 | 200 |  |
| **2.1** | 2021-02-01 9:00 AM | **2021-02-01 5:00 PM** | curtailed | 560 | 804 | grave shift split |
| **2.2** | **2021-02-01 5:00 PM** | 2021-02-01 7:00 PM | curtailed | 140 | 201 | grave shift split |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 7:00 PM | 2021-02-01 11:00 PM | down_for_maintenance | 0 | 302 |  |
| 4 | 2021-02-01 11:00 PM | 2021-02-02 3:00 AM | curtailed | 320 | 402 |  |
| **5.1** | 2021-02-02 3:00 AM | **2021-02-02 5:00 AM** | over_producing | 240 | 200 | day shift split |
| **5.2** | **2021-02-02 5:00 AM** | 2021-02-02 8:00 AM | over_producing | 360 | 302 | day shift split |
| 6 | 2021-02-02 8:00 AM | 2021-02-02 11:00 AM | normal_run | 280 | 301 |  |
| **7.1** | 2021-02-02 11:00 AM | **2021-02-02 5:00 PM** | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 602 | shift split |
| **7.2** | **2021-02-02 5:00 PM** | **2021-02-03 5:00 AM** | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 1205 | shift split |
| **7.3** | **2021-02-03 5:00 AM** | **2021-02-03 5:00 PM** | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 1205 | shift split |
| **7.4** | **2021-02-03 5:00 PM** | **2021-02-04 5:00 AM** | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 1205 | shift split |
| **7.5** | **2021-02-03 5:00 AM** | **2021-02-04 4:00 PM** | broken_belt_unscheduled_loss | 0 | 1105 | shift split |

so the end result can be then be `df.groupby(sum : tons)` per shift

for a start, I know it needs some kind of array creating UDF inside an `F.explode()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) to transform a single row into multiple rows.

**Step 1**: parse the date columns (if necessary, depends on the data source):

```python
df = spark.read....

dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
df = df.withColumn("event_start", F.to_timestamp(F.col("event_start"), dateformat)) \
       .withColumn("event_end", F.to_timestamp(F.col("event_end"), dateformat))
```

**Step 2**: define the actual logic. The function `split_shifts` takes a [row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=row#pyspark.sql.Row) and yields as many new rows as required:

```python
def split_shifts(r):
    import datetime as dt
    def get_next_end(start):
        if start.hour < 5:
            end = dt.datetime(year=start.year, month=start.month, day=start.day, hour=5)
        elif start.hour < 17:
            end = dt.datetime(year=start.year, month=start.month, day=start.day, hour=17)
        else:
            next_day = start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
            end = dt.datetime(year=next_day.year, month=next_day.month, day=next_day.day, hour=5)
        return end
    def calc_tons(start, end, current_start, current_end, tons):
        return (current_end-current_start)/(end-start)*tons

    row = r['row']
    event_start = r['event_start']
    event_end = r['event_end']
    operation_status = r['operation_status']
    tons_actual = r['tons_actual']
    tons_target = r['tons_target']

    current_event_start = event_start
    expected_event_end = get_next_end(current_event_start)
    while( expected_event_end < event_end):
        yield Row(row=row, event_start=current_event_start, event_end=expected_event_end, operation_status=operation_status, tons_actual=calc_tons(event_start, event_end, current_event_start, expected_event_end, tons_actual), tons_target=calc_tons(event_start, event_end, current_event_start, expected_event_end, tons_target))
        current_event_start = expected_event_end
        expected_event_end = get_next_end(current_event_start)
    yield Row(row=row, event_start=current_event_start, event_end=event_end, operation_status=operation_status, tons_actual=calc_tons(event_start, event_end, current_event_start, event_end, tons_actual), tons_target=calc_tons(event_start, event_end, current_event_start, event_end, tons_target))
```

**Step 3**: apply the `split_shifts` function using `flatMap`:

```python
df = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda r: split_shifts(r)).toDF()
```

**Step 4**: format the date columns as strings if necessary:

```python
df = df.withColumn("event_start", F.date_format(F.col("event_start"), dateformat)) \
       .withColumn("event_end", F.date_format(F.col("event_end"), dateformat))
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
|row|        event_start|          event_end|    operation_status|tons_actual|       tons_target|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
|  1| 2021-02-01 7:00 AM| 2021-02-01 9:00 AM|          normal_run|      197.0|             200.0|
|  2| 2021-02-01 9:00 AM| 2021-02-01 5:00 PM|           curtailed|      560.0|             803.2|
|  2| 2021-02-01 5:00 PM| 2021-02-01 7:00 PM|           curtailed|      140.0|             200.8|
|  3| 2021-02-01 7:00 PM|2021-02-01 11:00 PM|down_for_maintenance|        0.0|             301.0|
|  4|2021-02-01 11:00 PM| 2021-02-02 3:00 AM|           curtailed|      320.0|             402.0|
|  5| 2021-02-02 3:00 AM| 2021-02-02 5:00 AM|      over_producing|      240.0|             200.8|
|  5| 2021-02-02 5:00 AM| 2021-02-02 8:00 AM|      over_producing|      360.0|             301.2|
|  6| 2021-02-02 8:00 AM|2021-02-02 11:00 AM|          normal_run|      280.0|             301.0|
|  7|2021-02-02 11:00 AM| 2021-02-02 5:00 PM|broken_belt_unsch...|        0.0| 602.6037735849056|
|  7| 2021-02-02 5:00 PM| 2021-02-03 5:00 AM|broken_belt_unsch...|        0.0|1205.2075471698113|
|  7| 2021-02-03 5:00 AM| 2021-02-03 5:00 PM|broken_belt_unsch...|        0.0|1205.2075471698113|
|  7| 2021-02-03 5:00 PM| 2021-02-04 5:00 AM|broken_belt_unsch...|        0.0|1205.2075471698113|
|  7| 2021-02-04 5:00 AM| 2021-02-04 4:00 PM|broken_belt_unsch...|        0.0|1104.7735849056605|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks i will this today!